# Passing arguments to constructors using CreateObject in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, constructor, arguments, createobject

I'm trying to use a Java object in Coldfusion using the CreateObject function.

This works fine when the constructor in the Java class doesn't take any arguments e.g.:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
```

Goes to

```
myObject = CreateObject("java",  "com.something.MyObject");
```

But I'm not sure how to pass arguments to the constructor for code like this:

```
MyObject2 myObject2 = new MyObject2(myArgment);
```

I'm sure this should be really simple, but I can't find this anywhere.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass them in the init method like this:

```
myObject = CreateObject("java",  "com.something.MyObject").init(constructorArg1, constructorarg2);
```

Note that if you do NOT call init at all then you will be working with only static methods of the object and not an instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, calling the init() method on a java object invokes that object's constructor. Init() is not a real method of the object and is used only to call the constructor:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Java_7.html